# How to configure isis on Cisco router interface with two IPs

Tags: networking, router

Cisco routers are connected to the switch. There is no way to configure trunk interfaces on the switch. There are 2 ips configured on the interface of each router - primary and secondary. According to ISIS, the router receives routes only from the neighbor on the right and left. Ping to loopback interface from R5 to R1, for example, does not work. LSA database for R1 exists on R5. Is it possible to set it up so that everyone can see everyone? Thanks!

[image: topology]

```
R1#sh ip route isis
  
      12.0.0.0/8 is variably subnetted, 7 subnets, 2 masks
i L2     12.0.10.4/32 [115/20] via 12.10.5.4, 00:26:44, FastEthernet0/0
i L2     12.10.6.0/24 [115/20] via 12.10.5.4, 00:26:44, FastEthernet0/0


R2#sh ip rou isi

      12.0.0.0/8 is variably subnetted, 7 subnets, 2 masks
i L2     12.0.10.5/32 [115/20] via 12.10.7.5, 00:18:51, FastEthernet0/0
i L2     12.10.8.0/24 [115/20] via 12.10.7.5, 00:18:51, FastEthernet0/0


R3#sh ip rou isi

      12.0.0.0/8 is variably subnetted, 7 subnets, 2 masks
i L2     12.0.10.5/32 [115/20] via 12.10.8.5, 00:19:44, FastEthernet0/0
i L2     12.10.7.0/24 [115/20] via 12.10.8.5, 00:19:44, FastEthernet0/0


R4#sh ip ro isis

      12.0.0.0/8 is variably subnetted, 7 subnets, 2 masks
i L2     12.0.10.1/32 [115/20] via 12.10.5.1, 00:29:50, FastEthernet0/0
i L2     12.10.4.0/24 [115/20] via 12.10.5.1, 00:29:57, FastEthernet0/0

R5#sh ip rou isis
      12.0.0.0/8 is variably subnetted, 9 subnets, 2 masks
i L2     12.0.10.2/32 [115/20] via 12.10.7.2, 00:18:29, FastEthernet0/0
i L2     12.0.10.3/32 [115/20] via 12.10.8.3, 00:18:29, FastEthernet0/0
i L2     12.10.4.0/24 [115/20] via 12.10.8.3, 00:18:29, FastEthernet0/0
i L2     12.10.6.0/24 [115/20] via 12.10.7.2, 00:18:29, FastEthernet0/0


    R5#sh isis data

IS-IS Level-2 Link State Database:
LSPID                 LSP Seq Num  LSP Checksum  LSP Holdtime      ATT/P/OL
R1.00-00              0x00000007   0xDC3C        962               0/0/0
R2.00-00              0x00000006   0x22EE        739               0/0/0
R3.00-00              0x00000006   0x3CD1        739               0/0/0
R3.01-00              0x00000001   0xE116        0 (741)           0/0/0
R4.00-00              0x00000005   0x24E8        873               0/0/0
R4.01-00              0x00000004   0xD9DB        837               0/0/0
R5.00-00            * 0x00000006   0x659D        741               0/0/0
R5.01-00            * 0x00000004   0x0EA3        745               0/0/0
R5#sh isis data R1.00-00 detail


IS-IS Level-2 LSP R1.00-00
LSPID                 LSP Seq Num  LSP Checksum  LSP Holdtime      ATT/P/OL
R1.00-00              0x00000007   0xDC3C        954               0/0/0
  Area Address: 49.0001
  NLPID:        0xCC
  Hostname: R1
  IP Address:   12.0.10.1
  Metric: 10         IS-Extended R4.01
  Metric: 10         IP 12.0.10.1/32
  Metric: 10         IP 12.10.4.0/24
  Metric: 10         IP 12.10.5.0/24
R5#
```

PS. The same topology with trunks and subinterfaces works correctly. It seems like the problem is in several addresses on the router interface. But the Cisco manuals say what should work. Help me to understand, please.

[image]

```
R5#sh ip route isis

      12.0.0.0/8 is variably subnetted, 12 subnets, 2 masks
i L2     12.0.10.1/32 [115/30] via 12.10.8.3, 00:08:51, FastEthernet0/0.80
i L2     12.0.10.2/32 [115/20] via 12.10.7.2, 00:09:10, FastEthernet0/0.70
i L2     12.0.10.3/32 [115/20] via 12.10.8.3, 00:08:51, FastEthernet0/0.80
i L2     12.0.10.4/32 [115/30] via 12.10.7.2, 00:09:04, FastEthernet0/0.70
i L2     12.10.4.0/24 [115/20] via 12.10.8.3, 00:08:51, FastEthernet0/0.80
i L2     12.10.5.0/24 [115/30] via 12.10.8.3, 00:08:51, FastEthernet0/0.80
                      [115/30] via 12.10.7.2, 00:08:51, FastEthernet0/0.70
i L2     12.10.6.0/24 [115/20] via 12.10.7.2, 00:09:10, FastEthernet0/0.70

R5#ping 12.0.10.1
Type escape sequence to abort.
Sending 5, 100-byte ICMP Echos to 12.0.10.1, timeout is 2 seconds:
!!!!!
Success rate is 100 percent (5/5), round-trip min/avg/max = 48/65/80 ms
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I configured the zones and levels correctly so that routing loops would not form and everything worked.